# How to release onTouch event when ACTION_MOVE to certain points? Android

Tags: android, multi-touch

I have an `onTouch` event that work well with my `View`. Because of some reasons, I want to release the action `onTouch` after I move finger to some point of screen:

```
switch(event.getAction & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
    case ACTION_UP:
        // When I release the touch, Event goes here 
        break;
    case ACTION_DOWN:
        // when I touch screen, Event goes here
        break;
    case ACTION_MOVE:
        // When I move the finger, Event goes here
        break;

}
```

Is there any way to release the touch at `ACTION_MOVE` by code (not by my finger :D). Any suggestion is welcomed!

One more problem: I don't know the different between 2 functions: `event.getX()` and `event.getRawX()`. Can any one explains it? (some times, I use `getX()` and my code will goes wrong, but If I use `getRawX()`, it works well!!)

P/s: Sorry if there is any typing or English error!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to re-call the `onTouchEvent` function with an `ACTION_UP` value. You could use something like this:

```
if(wantToRelease) {
    MotionEvent newEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(event);  
    newEvent.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
    this.onTouchEvent(newEvent);
    return true;
}
```

The difference between `getX/Y()` and `getRawX/Y()` is that `getX/Y()` is adjusted for containers and views, which can sometimes be problematic if your event spans multiple views. `getRawX/Y()` is unadjusted

Comment: thanks you very much! What I must do, If I just want to interrupt `ACTION_MOVE`? Example, If user move finger through some point, normally, It's an `onTouch` event, but I want it to be 2 `onTouch` event? Can I do it? Thanks again!!

Comment: Can you help me one more times?